# Wordpress vimeo embed not working with https

Tags: vimeo

We have recently migrated our WordPress site in https. All Vimeo videos stopped working and the following error is displayed.

We are using this short code - [vimeo https://vimeo.com/ID-HERE]

wp-config

```
    <?php

/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'xx');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'xx');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'xx');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

/**#@+
 * Authentication Unique Keys and Salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases!
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This will force all users to have to log in again.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
define('AUTH_KEY',         'keys');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'keys');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'keys');
define('NONCE_KEY',        'keys');
define('AUTH_SALT',        'keys');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'keys');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'keys');
define('NONCE_SALT',       'keys');


/**#@-*/

/**
 * WordPress Database Table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each a unique
 * prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix  = 'wp_';

/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 */
define('WP_DEBUG', false);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

Comment: This is the error we are getting. - Blocked loading mixed active content “vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=https://vimeo.com/198306286‌​” example.com/post

Comment: any reason for pasting **wp-config** code?

Comment: No. just wanted to mention that no special SSL variables are defined in config.